# MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'Cantidad' in 'field list''

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, stock

I need to update my stock, whenever we buy a product, that quantity needs to be added to my stock. 
I am doing this update through **mysql**, I have two tables "`detalledecompra`" where we buy a product and "`productos`" which would be the stock, it contains the product id, description, quantity avaliable, etc. 
I thought about creating this trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER UPDATESTOCK AFTER INSERT ON detalledecompra
FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

UPDATE productos
SET productos.StockActual = StockActual + detalledecompra.Cantidad 
  WHERE productos.CodigoProducto = detalledecompra.CodigoProducto;

END;
```

but it cant find the column `detalledecompra.Cantidad`, my visual studio says

> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'Unknown column 'Cantidad' in
>   'field list''

how should I modify the trigger in order that whenever we buy something, that quantity will be added to the products "StockActual"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you are getting that error is because you are not joining to the detalledecompra table in your `UPDATE` query. That said, you don't need to use that table in this case.

When you create a trigger on an `INSERT`, your trigger has access to the `NEW` keyword, which gives access to the values that are being inserted. Because of this you don't actually need to access the detalledecompra directly in the trigger function.

This should work for you:

```
UPDATE productos
SET productos.StockActual = StockActual + NEW.Cantidad 
WHERE productos.CodigoProducto = NEW.CodigoProducto;
```

Here is some documentation on MySQL triggers and the `NEW` and `OLD` keywords: [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/trigger-syntax.html)